# How to write text in jupyter / ipython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

[Here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/temporaer/tutorial_ml_gkbionics/master/2%2520-%2520KMeans.ipynb) is an example of IPython notebook in which besides the input and output cells we have a plain text. How can I do the same in my IPython notebook? At the moment I have inly `In` and `Out` cells.

Comment: ½ the quesiton is off site. And the link does not meet accessability standards. ("here" does not describe the link).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Change the cell type to Markdown in the menu bar, from `Code` to `Markdown`. Currently in Notebook `4.x`, the keyboard shortcut for such an action is: `Esc` (for command mode), then `m` (for markdown).

Comment: is there anyway to edit the text like make italic or bolt or change font?

Answer (score 37):

As it is written in the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/notebook.html#markdown-cells) you have to change the cell type to a markdown.

[image]

Comment: If not use a webpage interface, this method does not work.

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1**: Click on the '+' to create a new cell, type some text in, and select 'Markdown' in the dropdown

[image]

**Step 2**: It should now look like this:

[image]

**Step 3**: Click anywhere in the cell and click on 'Run'. Now it looks how you expect it to.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Simply Enter <kbd>Esc</kbd> and type <kbd>m</kbd> it will convert to text cell.

Comment: This is the same as the answer of 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Matt's answer above (as I don't have comment privileges yet), one mouse-free workflow would be:

`Esc` then `m` then `Enter` so that you gain focus again and can start typing.

Without the last `Enter` you would still be in Escape mode and would otherwise have to use your mouse to activate text input in the cell.

Another way would be to add a new cell, type out your markdown in "Code" mode and then change to markdown once you're done typing everything you need, thus obviating the need to refocus.

You can then move on to your next cells. :)

Comment: That was unclear to me for so long. I always was nerved by having to click on that cell again to write.