# Jupyter notebook display code only

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebooks to write some explanations on how to use certain functions. The code i am showing there is not complete, meaning it will give errors when executed. Is there a way to write display-only code in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: You mean mark cells as text only like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804044/how-to-write-text-in-ipython-notebook?

Comment: If i use markdown it doesn't show code syntax coloring and identation

Comment: So you want mixed formatting? Why not just use docstrings or comments?

Comment: Because i want the code to be text only (not executing). If i comment my code, it doesn't have syntax highlighting anymore, and it also looks quite hackish.

Comment: You want [markdown](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/notebook.html#markdown-cells) then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change cell type to markdown
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, the ``` is kind of what i am looking for, but then with syntax coloring

Comment: Great! This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use markdowns. Or you can put in comment your code but it will be not in "jupyter way"